# hide only when i click outside

Tags: jquery, search

I don't want to hide when click to input. http://jsfiddle.net/bTHNh/1/

```
$("body").click(function() {
    $(".search-input").hide();
});


$("#search").click(function () {

    $(".search-input").toggle();

    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Try $(HTML).click instead of body.click

Comment: You aren't passing `event` in to your handler function, although I assume that's just an oversight in your fiddle, as it wouldn't work at all otherwise.

Comment: Can you edit at http://jsfiddle.net/bTHNh/1/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    //alert(event.target.className);
    if(event.target.className != 'search-input') {
        $(".search-input").hide();
    }
});


$("#search").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".search-input").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cmacu/bTHNh/4/